# SQL Server Data Tools v15.1.6: Cross-database index drop

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

I have a series of stored procs that run data migration between two databases. The procs sit in a Migration DB. Some of the procs create indexes on the source tables. However, I can't leave the indexes in place; I have to drop them when the procs are finished. When running the procs in SQL, this statement works fine:

```sql
drop index IX_SCA_RPTNBR_ASIGNTYPCD_ENDDT on CHILDSDB2.VLCHA.STAFF_CASE_ASIGN;
```

However, in SSDT, in order to not get a build error, I have to change that to:

```sql
drop index [$(CHILDSDB2)].VLCHA.STAFF_CASE_ASIGN.IX_SCA_RPTNBR_ASIGNTYPCD_ENDDT;
```

Then, when I go to publish the DB, I get the following error:

> 'DROP INDEX' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

So basically, the problem is that the SSDT publisher doesn't translate the statement that the SSDT compiler requires into a statement that the SQL Server query engine can handle.

Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround at least. I can use dynamic SQL to drop the indexes, which gets around the SSDT compiler. It's still not a real solution in my book, but it gets the job done.